# Show that $W(Y_{\tau \land k})$ is a martingale where Y is a Markov chain and that it converges almost surley

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales, markov-process, random-walk

My questions refers to this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-11/issue-2/A-Simple-Criterion-for-Transience-of-a-Reversible-Markov-Chain/10.1214/aop/1176993604.full) by T. Lyons. I'm quite new to stochastic processes.

Let $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a time-homogenous, recurrent, reversible Markov chain with statespace $X$ and transitions $p_{ij}$ for $i,j\in X$.
For reversibility there exist strictly positive weights $\pi_i, i\in X$ with $\pi_ip_{ij}=\pi_jp_{ji}$.
We denote the conditioned expected value and probability on $i\in X$ as $\mathbb{E}^i$ and $\mathbb{P}^i$.

Furthermore we have a function $W:X \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
(i) $W_{i_0}=0$ for a certain $i_0 \in X$
(ii) $W\neq 0$
(iii) $W_i=\sum_{j\in X}p_{ij}W_j$ for $i\neq i_0$
(iv) $\sum_{i,j\in X}\pi_ip_{ij}(W_i-W_j)^2<\infty$

Let $\tau$ be the first hitting time of $i_0$

**First question:**
Why is $W(Y_{\tau \land k})$ a $\mathbb{P}^i$ martingale?

**Second question:**  Why does $\lim_{k \to \infty}W(Y_{\tau \land k})=0$ a.s. hold?

---

**My thoughts:**
Regarding the first question my idea was to show that $W(Y)$ is a martingale and than make use of the optional stopping theorem. But somehow I'm confusing myself with this "under $\mathbb{P}^i$" condition. Let $\Sigma_k=\sigma({W(Y_{\tau \land l})}|l=1,...k)$ the induced sigma algebra. Do I have to show that for every $A \in \Sigma_s$ it holds that $$\Bbb{E}^i[\Bbb{E}[W(Y_{\tau \land m})|\Sigma_s]*\Bbb{1}_A]=\Bbb{E}^i[W(Y_{\tau \land s})*\Bbb{1}_A]$$ when $s \leq m$?

Regarding the second question I feel like we do need irreducibility? Why should $\Bbb{P}^i[\tau < \infty]=1$ if there is no way between $i$ and $i_0$? Is this somehow implicitly given?

Comment: The term "recurrent" applied to the chain $Y$ (not merely to one of its states) should be understood as meaning that the chain is irreducible and all states are recurrent. (N.B. For an irreducible chain, if one state is recurrent than all states are recurrent.)  This is standard usage, and certainly implicit in Lyons' discussion.